# The bottom textarea receive focus when click on the overlapped cancel button from actionsheet

Tags: ios, focus, textarea, touch, extjs

In my sencha touch 2 app, i had an textarea docked on then bottom. i also had an actionsheet in the same page. when actionsheet shows up, the 'Cancel button' in the actionsheet just over lapped on top of the textarea. So every time when click on the 'Cancel button' it caused the textarea underneath received 'focus' to bring up the soft keyboard.. it is very annoying... does anyone have solutions for this issue??

Regards,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try the following line of code-

```
Ext.getCmp('textAreaId').blur();
```